# Access HttpServletRequest anywhere

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, open-session-in-view

I used to have an Open Session In Conversation Filter based on cookies for a JSF 2 app. Now I want to build the same mechanism but technology-agnostic. Reusing some code, I have written this in a class that extends [OncePerRequestFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html):

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    UUID conversationId = lookupConversationOrCreateIfNecessary(request,
            response);

    log.debug("Binding conversation '{}' to request '{}'", conversationId,
            request);
    bindConversation(conversationId, request);

    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        log.debug("Unbinding conversation '{}' from request '{}'",
                conversationId, request);
        unbindConversation(conversationId, request);
    }

}
```

Now, when I reach `bindConversation(conversationId, request)` I just add a request attribute which points to the conversationId which is mapped to a Hibernate [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html).

Anyways, in JSF I can access the current request by using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()` and implemented a [CurrentSessionContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentSessionContext.html) using this. But in plain servlets how can I access the current request programmatically?

Note: I have been reading the OncePerRequestFilter javadocs and I found this:

> As of Servlet 3.0, a filter may be invoked as part of a REQUEST or
>   ASYNC dispatches that occur in separate threads. A filter can be
>   configured in web.xml whether it should be involved in async
>   dispatches. However, in some cases servlet containers assume different
>   default configuration. Therefore sub-classes can override the method
>   shouldNotFilterAsyncDispatch() to declare statically if they [sic] shouuld
>   indeed be invoked, once, during both types of dispatches in order to
>   provide thread initialization, logging, security, and so on. This
>   mechanism complements and does not replace the need to configure a
>   filter in web.xml with dispatcher types.

So, would it be dangerous to use a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to achieve what I want?

Comment: ThreadLocal is what JSF uses, so no it shouldn't be dangerous. JSF can do what it does because everything is routed through the singular FacesServlet where the instrumentation can happen. If you want to do something similar you'll have to use a similar strategy.

Comment: Yes, but if the filter is configured with ASYNC dispatch many threads would be using the mechanism. Unless those threads are spawned from the thread that runs the bindConversation code then I will get NullPointerExceptions. Isn't it? Also the cleanup would be tricky because if I put the request in a InheritableThreadLocal the container may use a pool and that would cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention in your question: using a ThreadLocal seems a good option. I don't see why it would be unsafe as soon as you use your filter for both REQUEST and ASYNC.

**EDIT**

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    UUID conversationId = lookupConversationOrCreateIfNecessary(request,
            response);

    log.debug("Binding conversation '{}' to request '{}'", conversationId,
            request);

    ConversationHolder.setId(conversationId);

    bindConversation(conversationId, request);

    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        log.debug("Unbinding conversation '{}' from request '{}'",
                conversationId, request);
        ConversationHolder.clear();
        unbindConversation(conversationId, request);
    }

}

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    return false; //to be sure both REQUEST and ASYNC are filtered
}
```

And the ConversationHolder

```
public class ConversationHolder extends ThreadLocal<UUID>{

    private static ConversationHolder INSTANCE = new ConversationHolder();

    public static void setId(UUID conversationId){
          INSTANCE.set(conversationId);
    }

    public static UUID getId(){
        return INSTANCE.get();
    }

    public static void clear(){
        INSTANCE.remove();
    }

}
```

Since conversationId is a local variable it won't be shared between request.

Since ConversationHolder is a ThreadLocal, the value you get from it during doFilter(...) will be correct. (except if you create new Thread by hand during your request processing, but it is not a recommended design)

Comment: I am concerned about cleanup, because the javadoc states plainly `The dispatcher type javax.servlet.DispatcherType.ASYNC introduced in Servlet 3.0 means a filter can be invoked in more than one thread over the course of a single request.`

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking, it looks like a HibernateTransactionManager but with one Session along many requests!